# laravel, how to store images to public_html directory

Tags: php, laravel, file, upload

On my hosting, I have `'public_html'`, not 'public' directory name I
I have bind public path to the `public_html directory in index.php` file

```
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
  return base_path().'/public_html';
});
```

now public_path() helper returns me path with public_html (correct)

What is more, i have my disk in the `filesystem.php` file

```
'my_upload' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path().'/images/adverts',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

Everything looks fine for me, but when I upload some files, laravel put them in `'public' directory`. I need to have them in `'public_html'`.

(I need images in public directory becouse my hosting does not provide link do storage folder)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try store files like this:

```
if(!Storage::disk('my_upload')->put($path, $file_content)) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Of course i tried to upload with your code. However, result is the same. Laravel still makes a 'public' directory. Do you have any different solution?

Comment: @ErykPerzewski check chmod youre directory 775

Comment: solution found. I think that laravel store old disk path in cache.

Comment: All i had to do was clearing a cache with command "php artisan config:clear". thanks for the answers

Comment: @ErykPerzewski super))